# python 3.X change offset 06 and 07 of a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an important amount of files that use at offset 06 and 07 "01 01" instead of "00 00", so I wanted to make a python script, but when running it, no error happens, and no file was changed. here the script I have :

```
for g in os.listdir('./'):
    if not os.path.isfile(g):
        continue
    file = open(g, "rb")
    magic = file.read(8)
    magic[6]==0
    magic[7]==0
```

edit : oh well I forgot to close the file, and 'rb'is for read binary only, so here my new code (that still don't work because character 00 doesn't exist)

```
for g in os.listdir('./'):
    if not os.path.isfile(g):
        continue
    with file(g, 'rb') as fh:
        patch1 = �
    with file(g, 'r+b') as fh:
        fh.seek(0x06)
        fh.write(patch1)
        fh.seek(0x07)
        fh.write(patch1)
```

edit3: thanks furas, I moved patch 1 to the top line, I was getting indentation error with it for some reason, here the final script that works ! :D

```
patch1 = b"\x00"
for g in os.listdir('./'):
    if not os.path.isfile(g):
        continue
    fh = open(g, "r+b")
    fh.seek(0x06)
    fh.write(patch1)
    fh.seek(0x07)
    fh.write(patch1)
    fh.close()
```

Comment: What were you expecting to happen? This code cannot alter files as it opens them in read mode. In any case nothing in your code would write anything to a file.

Comment: Did you forget to close the file? Often nothing will be saved unless you explicitly close the file

Comment: your script doesn't write anything. Especially 'magic[6]==0' is comparing rather than assigning.

Comment: you don't have to open file to set variable `patch1 = �`  But you could use `pint(g)` before `with` to see what file is changed. You can also check `print( os.getcwd() )` to check Current Working Directory - maybe you run it in different folder then you expect and it changes different folder then you check later.

Comment: you can use `write(b'\x00\x00')` to write both values at once - you don't have to seek to `0x07`